# Best way to do a 301 redirect from non-www to www. in IIS7.5?

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, 301-redirect

What's the best way to do a 301 redirect from non-www 'somedomain.com' to 'www.somedomain.com' in IIS7.5?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest that you install the URL [ReWrite module for IIS 7](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/) to do this for you. You would add a rule that looked soemthing like this

```
<rule name="Canonical Host Name" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="somedomain\.com$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.somedomain.com{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

See [this article](http://blogs.iis.net/ruslany/archive/2009/04/08/10-url-rewriting-tips-and-tricks.aspx) for some hints and tips on URL ReWrite.

Comment: Sam, Is the condition required in this case since you've already wildcarded the URL?